# how to cycle through the table with same data on fields?

Tags: delphi, delphi-7

hello i have this code running today but problem is that when there are same data on fields it doesnt cycle but just shows the first data that it filters.
here is the code

```
ADOTable1.First;
if ADOTable1.Locate('Last', Edit1.Text, []) then
begin
  Label1.Caption := ADOTable1.FieldByName('Last').AsString;
  Label2.Caption := ADOTable1.FieldByName('First').AsString;
  Label3.Caption := ADOTable1.FieldByName('address').AsString;
  Next;
end 
else
begin
  Label1.Caption := '';
  Label2.Caption := '';
  Label3.Caption := '';
end;
```

Comment: Locate did not filter, it is looking for a matching record and returns true if found and activate this record.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

[`Locate`](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/Libraries/XE2/en/Data.DB.TDataSet.Locate) locates the ***first*** record that matches the specified criteria in the DataSet.
If a record was found, that record becomes the active/current record.
It cannot be used to locate a "Next" match.
You might want to use a [`Filter`](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/Libraries/XE3/en/Data.DB.TDataSet.Filter) criteria with [`FindFirst`](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/Libraries/XE2/en/Data.DB.TDataSet.FindFirst)/[`FindNext`](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/Libraries/XE2/en/Data.DB.TDataSet.FindNext) e.g.:

```
DataSet.Filter := 'Last = ''' + Edit1.Text + '''';
if DataSet.FindFirst then
begin
  ShowMessage('Found First!');
  while DataSet.FindNext do
  begin
    ShowMessage('Found Next!');
  end;
end;
```

If you want to Filter all records that matches your criteria simply use:

```
DataSet.Filter := 'Last = ''' + Edit1.Text + '''';
DataSet.Filtered := True; // apply filter for the dataset
```

Now only those records that meet the filter's conditions are available in the DataSet.
Then iterate the DataSet:

```
DataSet.First;
while not DataSet.Eof do
begin
  // do something with the record
  DataSet.Next;
end;
```

Comment: thanks for the post kobik, it worked. sorry i had a late update, just got busy

Answer (score 0):

thanks. got this code so far last night

```
procedure TMain.Button1Click(Sender: TObject);

begin
ADOTable1.First;
while not ADOTable1.EOF do
begin
if (ADOTable1.FieldByName('Last Name').AsString = edit1.Text)
then begin
Label1.Caption := ADOTable1.FieldByName('Last Name').AsString;
Label2.Caption := ADOTable1.FieldByName('First Name').AsString;
Label3.Caption := ADOTable1.FieldByName('MI').AsString;
end;
ShowMessage('click ok for next profile');
ADOTable1.Next;
end;
```

it maybe same as the code you have given but this code searches for each line on the db grid and thus each line makes me press the ok button once.is it possible to click ok once then the code will search for the next matching data rather than it searching each row?

Comment: It is NOT the same code I posted. have you read my answer? have you tried it? what is your final objective?

Comment: sorry i was busy yesterday with work and got a chance now to review your post sorry i havent tested it yet, but will do now thanks...